# MySQL remote connection timeout and port 3306 close

Tags: networking, server, mysql, iptables

I've been searching through the whole a fix but nothing worked.

I'm trying to allow remote access to my MySQL db.

I've been editing my `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf` to modify bind address to set it to `0.0.0.0`, and enable port 3306 as allow for every machine.

**ufw status**

```
OpenSSH                    ALLOW       Anywhere
Apache Full                ALLOW       Anywhere
Apache                     ALLOW       Anywhere
Postfix                    ALLOW       Anywhere
Dovecot IMAP               ALLOW       Anywhere
Dovecot POP3               ALLOW       Anywhere
Dovecot Secure POP3        ALLOW       Anywhere
Dovecot Secure IMAP        ALLOW       Anywhere
3306/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
OpenSSH (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
Apache Full (v6)           ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
Postfix (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
Dovecot IMAP (v6)          ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
Dovecot POP3 (v6)          ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
Dovecot Secure POP3 (v6)   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
Dovecot Secure IMAP (v6)   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
3306/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

But when I'm looking if my port 3306 is open, it's telling me that it is closed (`nmap` doesn't find it as open and online service too)

I've already tried to delete bind address  instead of modifying it, same issue :/

At this stage, I've got no clue of what could be wrong, I've set a rule with iptable

```
iptables -A INPUT -i enp1s0 -p tcp --destination-port 3306 -j ACCEPT
```

Even this is not working.

Maybe it could help, but in my file of mysql conf, I've got `mysqlx-bind-address` which I've set to `0.0.0.0.0` too and tried to delete it too, not working.

I've been looking for skip network but it seems to be missing in my mysql conf.

At this stage, I'm very confused about what should I do to open my port 3306 and be able to access remotely to my MySQL db

Here is mysql conf :

```
#
# The MySQL database server configuration file.
#
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

# Here is entries for some specific programs
# The following values assume you have at least 32M ram

[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#
user        = mysql
# pid-file  = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
# socket    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
#port       = 3306
# datadir   = /var/lib/mysql


# If MySQL is running as a replication slave, this should be
# changed. Ref https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_tmpdir
# tmpdir        = /tmp
#
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
#bind-address = 0.0.0.0
#mysqlx-bind-address    = 0.0.0.0
#
# * Fine Tuning
#
key_buffer_size     = 16M
# max_allowed_packet    = 64M
# thread_stack      = 256K

# thread_cache_size       = -1

# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched
myisam-recover-options  = BACKUP

# max_connections        = 151

# table_open_cache       = 4000

#
# * Logging and Replication
#
# Both location gets rotated by the cronjob.
#
# Log all queries
# Be aware that this log type is a performance killer.
# general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/query.log
# general_log             = 1
#
# Error log - should be very few entries.
#
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
#
# Here you can see queries with especially long duration
# slow_query_log        = 1
# slow_query_log_file   = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
# long_query_time = 2
# log-queries-not-using-indexes
#
# The following can be used as easy to replay backup logs or for replication.
# note: if you are setting up a replication slave, see README.Debian about
#       other settings you may need to change.
# server-id     = 1
# log_bin           = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
# binlog_expire_logs_seconds    = 2592000
max_binlog_size   = 100M
# binlog_do_db      = include_database_name
# binlog_ignore_db  = include_database_name

# Prestashop special conf
read_buffer_size            = 2M 
read_rnd_buffer_size        = 1M
join_buffer_size            = 2M 
sort_buffer_size            = 2M
innodb_buffer_pool_size     = 1G
```

I'm on a digital ocean vps, if that can help.

By the way, I don't have any errors in my logs and my website is still working perfectly.

**More info :**

I've reproduce : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-allow-remote-access-to-mysql on a second vps, with the same configurations of mysql, php and apache, and it's working, I've contacted Digital Ocean support team because I can't understand why my port 3306 is still blocked after reproducing identicaly what I've done on my second vps.

Here is my `netstat -plant | grep 3306`

```
tcp6       0      0 :::33060                :::*                    LISTEN      33071/mysqld
tcp6       0      0 :::3306                 :::*                    LISTEN      33071/mysqld
```

Comment: The `#` at the start of a line in your config file means the row is a comment. You may want to remove the octothorp (`#`) from the line that sets `bind-address`. From there, restart MySQL and you may find remote access is enabled. BE WARNED that allowing your MySQL database to be accessed by any machine on the internet comes with inherent risk. Generally this is not done when a database server is on the open web. Connecting via SSH is general practice 

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. As I said in my post, I’ve already tried to set bind address to 0.0.0.0.0 without the comment sign

Comment: My bad I meant 0.0.0.0. I will look for ssh if you tell me that the best practice

Comment: After looking the ssh solution, it doesn't answer to my requirements, I need to be able to use multiple db in the same time

Comment: Have the same problem and haven't found an answer yet. I did all the same things as you did.